# CK editor content unknown temp image tag generetaed

Tags: php, jquery, ckeditor, mathjax

I am using Ckeditor for add maths Questions with Latex equation. some of the questions are inserted with 
`<img src="file:///C:\Users\USERAD~4\AppData\Local\Temp\msohtmlclip1\01\clip_image001.wmz" />` file.

i dont know where this tag is generated.how to stop this?

Answer (score 2):

That's content that has been copied from MS Word. It's been a long time, so I don't remember if it's possible to convert a .wmz into another format in which case the only (and simplest) solution is to remove those references.

If you can manage to convert them on the server to another standard image format, then you can upload them with something like the [Images From Word](http://www.uritec.es/imagesfromword/) plugin for CKEditor